# How to insert Entailment Symbol into Word Document?

Tags: microsoft-word, special-characters, symbols

How can I insert the [entailment symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_symbols) into a Microsoft Word 2007 document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Type in:

```
255E
```

then press alt + x  That will replace the 255E with ╞  (Though it looks better in word)

You can also go to Insert Symbols (or Insert tab and then Symbol in Office 2007)

Then select subset "Box Drawing" to see other options.  The shortcut is shown at the bottom of the dialog.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is still looking for this 12 years on..

In newer versions of office products, you can get many symbols by typing  latex-like names after a backslash - e.g. for the "entails" symbol, you can type "\models" - I found this on the [Wikipedia List of Logic Symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols)

Answer (score 0):

Copy/paste from wikipedia works for me

EDIT:
other ways: Insert symbols from Insert menu then lookup character 22A8 in Arial Unicode MS

or copy this: ⊧ (from wikipedia / green column)

Comment: yes but then you got the picture of the symbol. and additionally i dont wont to have to open wikipedia if i try to insert this symbol

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft Word has a Formula Editor designed to do exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: i don't think so, or can you tell me where to find it int the formula editor?

Answer (score 0):

Well You could try the Character Map in system tools..I am not sure but it has somewhat similiar symbol in it...

Answer (score 0):

I see something that looks like that in the Word 2007 equation editor. When you're on the equation tools design tab, click the drop down next to "Basic Math" and choose "Operators". In the last grouping (Advanced Relational Operators) I have almost three complete rows of symbols and it is next to last on the second row. Of course this location depends on the resolution of your computer. That looks like the symbol you seek, but you are beyond my math level so maybe I'm just falling for something similar.